# Is there a way in excel to transpose an entire column of data, yet only display cells that contain text (or values)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example of data I am looking at

[image]

Example of end result I am trying to achieve automatically

[image]

Comment: Sort the data block using each column as the primary key in turn before hand. This will effectively remove the 'whitespace. Now you can copy and paste special, transpose.

Comment: is there a way to do this without any manual sorting? the data will change regularly based on what happns in other sheets so trying to make this 100% foolproof

Answer (score 1):

Put the following formula into any cell (E5 in my sample image) and fill right one column then down three rows.

```
=INDEX($A:$C,IF(COLUMN(A:A)=1, 1, MATCH(1E+199,INDEX($A:$C,, ROW(1:1)))), ROW(1:1))
```

[image: Transpose loose data with formula]

Comment: this is VERY close to what I am after. what if there are multiple different values??? example - http://i.imgur.com/IeeSHwk.jpg

Comment: To search and collate an undetermined number of cells will require either a very complex array formula or a VBA macro or VBA User Defined function (aka UDF).

Comment: tips for building the array?